# Creating not rectangle control for input

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, controls

Writing an app for Windows Phone, I want to create custom control, inherited from `TextBlock`. But form of this control should be not rectangular. I tried to use Blend for this task, but I couldn't find properties to change form of controls.

[image: desirable form of custom control]

On the image above there is schematic form of control. I suppose, that there is possibility to set coordinates of angles of control, but I didn't find it. Thank you.

Comment: The text will be on either side?

Comment: the text will be into border.

Comment: I understood, but only horizontally or vertically?

Comment: sorry, only horizontally.

Comment: Why not just create a style with a specialized control template to alter the look of a certain `TextBox` instead of inheritance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved in several ways, I chose to use a `Template` with their figures. In the role of the figures will be performing standard `Rectangles`. Template for `TextBlock` can not be set, so I opted for a more universal control - `Label`.

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Width="30" Height="70" Fill="Gainsboro" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Panel.ZIndex="0" />
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="33,0,0,25" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
                        <Rectangle MinWidth="55" Height="30" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Gainsboro" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,30,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Declared `Label` in XAML:

```
<Label Background="Transparent" Width="200" Height="90" Content="Test your label" />
```

`Output`

[image]

Naturally, you will need to change the `Template` to fit your needs.

`Note about several ways`:

- For a more sophisticated method and more advanced ways you can use your own `Decorator`, where with the help of `DrawingContext` you will draw your object. Example - [How can I draw a border with squared corners in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678426/how-can-i-draw-a-border-with-squared-corners-in-wpf)
- Using the properties of the `Geometry`, where a `Path`, setting the desired shape of the figure. Example - [WPF freeform border control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356999/wpf-freeform-border-control).

Comment: thank you! there is no Label control in windows phone, and class Decorator only is in WPF, but I'll rewrite you way.